# add custom header to all laravel socialite requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm using socialite with a custom provider that requires an `X-User-Agent` header for all requests to the API. I've tried using this format in my `routes/web.php` but the API still throws an error that the header is not found:

```
$user = Socialite::driver('myprovider')
    ->with(['X-User-Agent' => 'CustomValue'])
    ->user();
```

Is there a place I can add this custom header to all requests to the provider?